# Retornar parcelas de um array por extenso (string)- PHP

Tags: php

Olá,

Eu tenho um `array` de parcelas, e quero retornar por `extenso`, resumidamente a `quantidade de parcelas` e os `valores`.

**Exemplo**

- Entrada de R$ 15,00 + 3 parcelas de R$ 15,00

No meu código de teste, não consegui obter este resultado, nem utilizando `foreach`

```
<?php

    $installments = [];
    for ($x = 0; $x < 4; $x++) {
        $installments[$x]['installment'] = $x + 1;
        $installments[$x]['value'] = 15.0;
    }
    $policy['installment'] = $installments;
    $policy['in_full']     = get_in_full($installments);

    function get_in_full($installments) {
        foreach ($installments as $installment)
        {
            return 'result';
        }
        //return 'Entrada de R$ 15,00 + 3 parcelas de R$ 15,48';
    }

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($policy);
    echo '</pre>';

?>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Com o seguinte código obtive o resultado que você deseja.

```
function get_in_full($installments) {
  // Valor da entrada
  $value = number_format($installments[0]['value'], 2);

  // Valor da primeira parcela
  $installmentValue = number_format($installments[1]['value'], 2);

  return 'Entrada de R$ '. $value .' + '. (count($installments) - 1) .' parcelas de R$ '. $installmentValue;
}
```